# python: sorting list of dicts by one key OR another

Tags: python

Have a `list` of `dict` objects where 50% will have a key `name` and 50% will have a key `full_name` and I'd like it sorted alphabetically based on either key.

Some sort function like:

```
if 'name' in a:
    a_name = a['name']
elif 'full_name' in a:
    a_name = a['full_name']
# repeat with a b in the compare, sort based on value
```

Is there a more efficient way here?

Comment: That’s not really a duplicate of this. This one has the added complication that you need to select one of two keys.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, IMHO, this is not a duplicate. The question you mentioned did tell about multiple keys, but this question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work:

```
sorts = sorted(data, key= lambda x: x.get('name') or x.get('full_name'))
```

Comment: May I know the reason of downvoting? I think it works.

Comment: Yes, it’s a good approach, I think, as long as there aren’t any empty strings in the data. Possibly slightly faster than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate both strings, substituting an empty string for the missing one:

```
lst.sort(key=lambda d: d.get('name', '') + d.get('full_name', ''))
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a lambda based functional approach:

```
testList = sorted(testList, key=lambda name: a_name['name'] if 'name'   in a_name else a_name['full_name'])
```